# Cardinality Question

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, infinity

I am just trying to see if my answers are correct to this question.

a) $\mathbb N$

b) $P$($\mathbb N$)

c) $\mathbb N$

Is this correct?

[image]

Comment: Looks good. The differences between *set* and *sequence* are order-significance and element-repetition (both invalid for sets and valid for sequences). But that does not impact the answer. In both questions (a and c), you can show a bijection to $\mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 1):

Your answers are correct. Finite subsets of $\mathbb N$ correspond to $\mathbb Q\cap(0,1]$ ( consider decimal expression ). Similarly infinite subsets of $\mathbb N$ correspond to $\mathbb R\cap(0,1]$ and finite sequences correspond to finite sets.